# OpenPayU hash structure in Ruby example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, hash

Today I'm fighting against the [OpenPayU Gem](https://github.com/PayU/openpayu_ruby)

This gem gives to the user the ability to connect with the PayU API and use their POS service.

Its use is extremely simple: you build an hash and encrypt it using a key they gave you; when you send your purchase data to the platform you add the encrypted hash to the POST request and they validate your post encrypting with the same key the data you sent. If the result is the same of the encrypted hash you sent, they let you continue with the purchase, otherwise they raise an error.

To learn to use it they gives you a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FDrsF/172/)

As first step I tried to build by hand my hash to be sure I'm sending the correct information to the platform. But I'm unable to do it, there is something wrong in my hash structure which make my result different as it should be. But what?

Here is their form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.payu.com/api/v2/orders">
    <input type="hidden" name="CustomerIp" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MerchantPosId" value="145227" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Description" value="Order description" />
    <input type="hidden" name="CurrencyCode" value="PLN" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TotalAmount" value="1000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Products.Product[0].Name" value="Product 1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Products.Product[0].UnitPrice" value="1000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Products.Product[0].Quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="CompleteUrl" value="http://localhost/continue" />
    <input type="hidden" name="OpenPayu-Signature" value="sender=145227;algorithm=MD5;signature=34267d8d3844d90af7a4aac24f8ee5e4" />
    <button type="submit" formtarget="_blank" >it works!</button>
</form>
```

and here is my hash:

```
 myhash = {
   'CustomerIp' => '127.0.0.1',
   'MerchantPosId' => '145227',
   'Description' => 'Order description',
   'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
   'TotalAmount' => '1000',
   'CompleteUrl' => 'http://localhost/complete',
   'Products' => {
     'Product' => [{
       'Name' => 'Product 1',
       'UnitPrice' => '1000',
       'Quantity' => '1'
     }]
   }
 }
```

To check if my hash is right I do the following:

```
my hash <%= OpenPayU.sign_form(myhash).inspect %>
<hr/>
should be = "sender=145227;signature=34267d8d3844d90af7a4aac24f8ee5e4;algorithm=MD5"
```

and is not.

Reading the gem code I have found the merchant_id and the key they use for that example:

```
merchant_pos_id: '145227'
signature_key: 13a980d4f851f3d9a1cfc792fb1f5e50
```

The signature I get is different. This means there is something wrong in my hash but I can't find the error.

Comment: The immediate difference I can see is that the HTML form requires `Products.Product[0]` yet you are sending a hash `Products => { Products => ...}` - change the second level of your `Products` hash to be `Product` (singular)

Comment: Just tested. And sadly it doesn't work.